# NestJS & MongoDB | CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "1" at path "_id" for model "Player"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, mongoose, nestjs

I am currently implementing a demo application to get to know the NestJS framework with mongoDB.

I am currently facing the following error message, which I cannot fix:

> failed for value "1" at path "_id" for model "Player" + 40997ms
>   CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "1" at path "_id" for
>   model "Player"

My controller looks like this:

```
@Controller('/players')
export class PlayersController {
    constructor(private playersService: PlayersService) { }

    @Get('/:id')
    async getPlayer(@Res() res, @Param('id') id: number) {
        const player = await this.playersService.getPlayer(id);
        if (!player) throw new NotFoundException('Player does not exist!');
        return res.status(HttpStatus.OK).json(player);
    }
}
```

My service looks like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class PlayersService {
    constructor(@InjectModel('Player') private readonly playerModel: Model<Player>) { }

    async getPlayer(playerId: number): Promise<Player | undefined> {
        const player = await this.playerModel.findById(playerId);
        return player;
    }
}
```

My DTO looks like this:

```
export class CreatePlayerDto {
    readonly id: number;
    readonly name: string;
    readonly score: number;
    readonly created_at: Date;
    readonly is_deleted: boolean;
}
```

My model looks like this:

```
export class Player extends Document {
    readonly id: number;
    readonly name: string;
    readonly score: number;
    @Exclude() readonly createdAt: Date;
    @Exclude() readonly isDeleted: boolean;
}
```

My mongoose schema looks like this:

```
export const PlayerSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    id: Number,
    name: String,
    score: Number,
    createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    isDeleted: Boolean
});
```

Example mongoDB entry after typing db.players.find()

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e5fccac9d16bf2d325cd57a"), "id" : 1, "name" : "Player One", "score" : 0, "createdAt" : "2020-04-03", "isDeleted" : false }
```

What am I doing wrong here or how can I fix this Error?

Comment: Try to change mongoose schema `_id: Number,`

Comment: @Valijon nope, doesn't work. I've updated my question and added an example mongoDB entry.

Comment: As you can see, you have `_id` and `id` fields. Do you want only single `id` field as PK wchich should be numeric? `.findById` searches by `_id` field and expectes `ObjectId` in this case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Why you are having the error:**
In the service, you have this piece of code that is attempting to find a player document from the DB: `this.playerModel.findById(playerId);`

The value of the `playerId` in that query is a string(or number after casting), however, the mongoose method `model.findById` internally is doing something like this: `this.playerModel.find({ _id: playerId });` and from the sample DB output you added to the question, you can see that _id is an ObjectId not a string or number, consequently you get the error `CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value “1” at path “_id” for model “Player”`

**The fix:**
There are two things you can do:
1. Update the query to use id instead of _id. You query would then be something like this: `this.playerModel.find({ id: playerId });`
2. Update your schema so that the _id property is a number and not ObjectID(the default). If you do this, you would have to ensure the uniqueness of the _id value. Your query wouldn't need to change if you do this. You schema would then be something like this:

```
export const PlayerSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    _id: Number,
    name: String,
    score: Number,
    createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    isDeleted: Boolean
});
```

If the is no hard requirement to have the _id field a number, you can use ObjectId values instead of Number, this would save you the stress of ensuring the uniqueness of the _id field. To do this, set the _id property as `_id: mongoose.ObjectId` in the schema.

You also need to update the dto, model and every other place you have the player object typed to reflect the schema update i.e addition of "_id" property with a different type and *maybe* the removal of the former "id" property.

**In case you are wondering how the _id field got there**; it is a property of every MongoDB document, it serves as the primary key. Even if you do not add it in your schema, either the MongoDB driver(mongoose in this case) or the mongod server would add it for you. More details [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#the-id-field)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I now understand the cause of the error. But how do I update my mongoose schema? I didn't define an "_id" in my schema (see above). This was automatically created by mongoDB (in addition to my "id" property).

Comment: I just added what the updated schema would be like to the answer.

Comment: Jut to re-emphasize, if you would be using a Number value for the _id property, you have to ensure the _id value is unique across the collection i.e if a document already has an _id of 1, any other document in that collection can't have that _id value otherwise you get errors.

Comment: Isn't there any way to use the _id of type ObjectId to ensure uniqueness? It doesn't work this way. With the suggested schama the _id is not in the response after doing a GET request to /players and after reloading the page a node error occurs: 

Error [ERR_INTERNAL_ASSERTION]: This is caused by either a bug in Node.js or incorrect usage of Node.js internals.
Please open an issue with this stack trace at https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues

Comment: ..and what about my model and dto? Do I need to change them as well?

Comment: Yes, you need to update them. I believe they've got some type checking going on that is stripping out the _id field and enforcing that id must be a part of every Player documents. Try updating them and let's see if that works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209759/discussion-between-tunmee-and-codehan25).

Answer (score 0):

An option if you don't want to modify mongo's default `_id` is to check if the player exists by using mongoose's Types.ObjectId.isValid function. This sample code has definetily room for improvement but shows a grasp of the idea:

```js
import { Model, Types } from 'mongoose';

...
async getPlayer(playerId: number) {
    try {
      const objectId = Types.ObjectId.isValid(playerId) ? new Types.ObjectId(playerId) : null;

      if (objectId) {
        const player = await this.playerModel.findById(objectId).exec();
        if (player) {
          return player;
        } else {
          throw new NotFoundException(`Player with id ${id} not found`);
        }
      } else {
        throw new BadRequestException(`Invalid player ID: ${id}`);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      throw new NotFoundException(`Failed to find player by id ${id}.`);
    }
    ...
```

Comment: Aniother alternative is to use a PipeFilter catching the Mongoose CastError and updating error message to something more intuitive